# Run as administrator in XP problem

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, cygwin

I have problem, I am logged as admin in XP, I have installed **cygwin** in `C:\cygwin`, but when I run some program which call bash inside cygwin like I don't have privileges to run, it give me error

> `CANNOT FIND SPECIFIED FILE`

But file is there, I see, I checked 1000 times. How to run like administrator like in Windows 7 ?

(My current user has admin privileges ). Can anybody help please ?

Comment: "CANNOT FIND SPECIFIED FILE ." How about the path settings?

Comment: Edit your question to show the exact command you are using, please. Also, @Aki is quite correct, it's likely the file is there but Cygwin can't "find" it because it isn't in the default search path. To help find that out, please edit your question to show the location of "the file".

Answer (score 1):

If your account is in the Administrators group in XP, you don't need the "Run as Administrator" feature from Windows 7 - everything you do already has administrator privileges behind it; you can't elevate any higher.  It's probably not a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file and select Run As...

You may need to hold shift when right clicking.